# nginx won't redirect http to https

Tags: nginx, https, http, redirect, 301-redirect

I have a nginx docker running, with *multiple* `site-config` files.

One of those is just a general redirect for all http connnections to https:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name *.example.com example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

all the other `site-config` files are for my other dockers/services like Nextcloud and Plex.

Whenever I type for example https://plex.example.com into my browser of choice (and even IE), it will show the correct webpage with an ssh-connection.

But, entering http://plex.example.com will just return an empty page and won't redirect me to Plex in this case.

Anyone got an idea?

**PS:**
The default `site-config` file is empty. But due to the fact, that all the `site-configs` of the services/dockers are working, I'm guessing, that having the redirect in an extra file won't be the problem.

**PPS:**
Here is an example access-log. The error-log is empty (no new entry for more than 3 months).
The log is from accessing my plex-server via https. Accessing anything via http won't create an log entry.

```
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1650 "https://plex.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/main.8883144fb7acc2430ef50eda6c1a41c8.css HTTP/1.1" 200 764765 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/main.v3.3a6aa4986f36a5810792d74118deda14.css HTTP/1.1" 200 214735 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/js/vendors-1-d55a6a600958df7159e4-plex-3.20.7-d87fe16.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1148751 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/js/main-0-2a819e76950d4ad197a8-plex-3.20.7-d87fe16.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3259450 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/common/img/backgrounds/preset-dark.5b95c8c24aab87067b69bca7ae11759a.png HTTP/1.1" 200 40582 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/translations/de.json HTTP/1.1" 200 128137 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:02 +0100] "GET /web/common/img/backgrounds/noise.0e9cf16a17adb19690cd31312cdaa809.png HTTP/1.1" 200 94668 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:03 +0100] "GET /web/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:03 +0100] "GET /?X-Plex-Product=Plex%20Web&X-Plex-Version=3.20.7&X-Plex-Client-Identifier=yi606rcck7j3x9lx3wafhzgx&X-Plex-Platform=Internet%20Explorer&X-Plex-Platform-Version=11.0&X-Plex-Device=Windows&X-Plex-Device-Name=Plex%20Web%20%28Internet%20Explorer%29&X-Plex-Device-Screen-Resolution=1149x738%2C2560x1440 HTTP/1.1" 401 157 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:03 +0100] "GET /identity?X-Plex-Product=Plex%20Web&X-Plex-Version=3.20.7&X-Plex-Client-Identifier=yi606rcck7j3x9lx3wafhzgx&X-Plex-Platform=Internet%20Explorer&X-Plex-Platform-Version=11.0&X-Plex-Device=Windows&X-Plex-Device-Name=Plex%20Web%20%28Internet%20Explorer%29&X-Plex-Device-Screen-Resolution=1149x738%2C2560x1440 HTTP/1.1" 200 160 "https://plex.example.com/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:21:53:06 +0100] "POST /index.php/heartbeat HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

**P3S:**
The result for `curl -i http://cloud.example.com/`:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='unRAID SMU'
Server: emhttp
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 16

401 Unauthorized
```

Access-log-entry: no entry created

The result for `curl -i https://cloud.example.com/`:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 21:20:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.9
Set-Cookie: oc367h1rrnkw=6033cj2p99saalb4csog6k47p5; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: oc_sessionPassphrase=SECRETPASSPHRASE; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-cHlJeHJhUFhzZWJmdDdwSWVkVisrYUFPMGVVd1p1eDJXSW44TkhESE9HND06eVZ0dzFPU1p3N1d1OE1BdEhib3cxdk1obWFwMFBvSThhc0dVZnlTZ0NUMD0='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self';
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: __Host-nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; path=/; httponly;secure; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2100 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=lax
Set-Cookie: __Host-nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true; path=/; httponly;secure; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2100 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=strict
Location: https://cloud.example.com/index.php/login
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Robots-Tag: none
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
Front-End-Https: on
```

Access-log-entry:

```
192.168.0.2 - - [13/Nov/2017:22:24:11 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

**P4S**
The result for `netstat -natup | grep nginx`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      305/nginx.conf
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      305/nginx.conf
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56973     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56977     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56981     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56722     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56976     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56980     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56971     ESTABLISHED 336/nginx: worker p
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.5:443          192.168.0.2:56966     ESTABLISHED 335/nginx: worker p
```

Comment: What do the access and error logs say? Please edit your question to include one or two appropriate log entries.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually hitting nginx?

Comment: Giving us a bunch of log entries isn't that useful. Do a curl that demonstrates the problem, give us the single log entry for that. Make it easy for people to help you. Show the curl output, which ideally should include response headers - it's a flag to curl.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry for that, but I am not good enough to decide what is useful out of these logs and what is not. Thus, I decided I'll give you as much information as possible (Curl is following)

Comment: Does nginx listen to port 80? Check it with `netstat -natup | grep nginx`. You are getting `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` for some reason. I guess it's not that config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.
First, something about my server/setup: its monitoring GUI runs on port 80 by default, never cared to change that.
All I did was mapping the external port 80 to the port 84 on my server. With 84 being the port let'sencrypt/nginx is listening.

Now with the recent software update for my router, it chose to ignore the port mapping while accessing the URL from within my LAN.
Thus, I was accessing the servers GUI via the http request and got the `Access Denied` error in the curl.

Got the idea after I tracert'ed the connection to my server.

I'll probably change the port of the server GUI to something else. But for now I'm happy, everything was always working fine